# PHP finding the expired time in seconds

Tags: php

Let say we have start date and end date

```
 if (isset($_POST['start_date']))
    $_POST['start_date'] = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['start_date']));

 if (isset($_POST['end_date']))
    $_POST['end_date'] = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['end_date']));
```

would  `$_POST['end_date'] - $_POST['start_date']` give you the expired time in seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to get the expired time in seconds you would use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
$expired = strtotime($_POST['end_date'])-strtotime($_POST['start_date']);

if (isset($_POST['start_date']))
    $_POST['start_date'] = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['start_date']));

if (isset($_POST['end_date']))
    $_POST['end_date'] = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['end_date']));

if (isset($_POST['start_date']) && isset($_POST['end_date'])) echo 'Expired time in seconds: ' . $expired;
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function to get the unix timestamp from a date literal, which is in milliseconds.

```
$startDate = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
$endDate = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

$diffInSeconds = ($endDate - $startDate) / 1000; // 1 second = 1000 miliseconds
```